# Reduce or solve calculative errors in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, precision, floating-accuracy

Sometimes simple algebra can result in floating accuracy errors.
in this case, I encountered `12 * 1.6` which resulted in `19.20000000003`

Is there a way to catch this issue or prevent it from happening?
Accuracy is highly important so simply rounding or truncation would not be enough.

Comment: The reason for the error is that 1.6 in binary has infinite decimals. We can maybe point out possible solutions if you provide more context.

Comment: @DIGI_Byte wrote:  "Accuracy is highly important" what actually do you mean by that?

Comment: dealing with money and crypto currency values

Answer (score -1):

No. Its the nature of floating point arithmetic. You only have so much accuaracy.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic